# Extract information from array in php

Tags: php

I have to take from the form input the following information

```
Jack - 80,55,77
Jim - 50,60,70
```

From this information, I have to extract the grades and find the average
The problem with my code is as follows:
In the first case, everything is fine 80+55+77/3
In the second case, my code takes 80+55+77+50+60+70  I need only 50+60+70

The output has to be:
Jack's average grade is 70
Jim's average grade is 60

This is my code:

```
<?php
$elements = [];
$sum=0;
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
  $elements[] = trim($line);
}
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $input = explode( ' - ', $element );
    $grades=explode(",",$input[1]);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($grades); $i++) { 
        $sum+=$grades[$i];
    }
    print "<p>". $input[0]."'s average grade is ".floor($sum/count($grades))."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to reset `$sum` after each element, so move it from the top to before the `for()`.

Comment: FYI you don't have to manually add the elements, there's a built-in function for that: `$avg = array_sum($grades) / count($grades);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset sum for each student:

```
<?php
$elements = [];
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
    $elements[] = trim($line);
}
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $input = explode( ' - ', $element );
    $grades=explode(",",$input[1]);
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($grades); $i++) { 
        $sum+=$grades[$i];  
    }
    print "<p>". $input[0]."'s average grade is ".floor($sum/count($grades))."</p>";
}
?>
```